# How to dynamically add week name with dates starting from monday as table header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dynamic

I am trying to create a c# mvc application for displaying timsheets of each employee. I want to create a table dynamically and the table header should contain the values as:

**Mon
 20-04-2020 |Tue 21-04-2020|Wed 22-04-2020|Thu 23-04-2020|Fri 24-04-2020|Sat 25-04-2020|Sun 26-04-2020**

I am a beginner so i don't know much about it and stuck on it from a while. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, so we can get you help were you are stuck.

Comment: Is formatting the date string your problem? Or a ui control? I am voting to close this question, since it's to vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the current week days, starting from Monday you can do this :

```cs
var today = DateTime.Now;       
var startDate = today.AddDays(-(((today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday) + 7) % 7));
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(7);
var currentWeekDays = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(x => startDate.AddDays(x));
```

And if you want to format a date to get `Mon 20-04-2020`, you can use the format `"ddd dd-MM-yyyy"`.

To conclude, you can obtain `Mon 20-04-2020|Tue 21-04-2020|Wed 22-04-2020|Thu 23-04-2020|Fri 24-04-2020|Sat 25-04-2020|Sun 26-04-2020` by doing this :

```cs
var formattedCurrentWeekDays = currentWeekDays.Select(d => d.ToString("ddd dd-MM-yyyy")).ToList();
var result = string.Join("|", formattedCurrentWeekDays);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```